# Why is regioncentroid not giving correct results?

Tags: finite-element-method, regions, computational-geometry, wave-equation

I am trying to calculate and plot the x-axis of a volume centroid for the region between zx-plane and a function squared $u(t,x,z)$ from time $t=15$ to $25$. The function is a numerical solution to a particular wave equation, codes of which I will attach at the end.

The code I used to obtain the position of this volume centroid is as follows:

```
centroid[t_] := 
  RegionPlot3D[
     0 <= z <= 75 && 0 <= y <= uwave[t, x, z]^2, {z, 0, 75}, {y, 
      0,.2}, {x, -1, 1}] // DiscretizeGraphics // RegionCentroid;
```

Take one particular time-instance, for example $t=18$. The plot of our function squared in 3D looks like this:
[image]

and its code is

```
Plot3D[uwave[18, x, z]^2, {x, -1, 1}, {z, 0, 75}, PlotPoints -> 200, 
 PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {"x", "z", "u"}]
```

Now clearly we would expect the centroid to have a x-axis slightly before $x=20$ as can be seen from the plot given. However, when I calculate it using the centroid function defined above, I find that

```
First[centroid[18]]
```

gives a value of 37.4976 which is clearly wrong. Where did I do wrong in the code?

For completeness, the numerical solution $uwave(t,x,z)$ is obtained by the following code which you may copy paste run, and get a result within 15 minutes.

```
Lx = 85;
Lz = 75;
Domain = Region[Rectangle[{-Lx, -Lz}, {Lx, Lz}]];

\[Rho]in = 5;
\[Rho]ex = 1;
w = 1;
p = 8;
\[Rho][x_] := (\[Rho]in - \[Rho]ex) (Sech[(x/w)^p])^2 + \[Rho]ex;
wx = 1;
wz = Sqrt[2];
u0saus[x_, z_] := x/wx*Exp[-(x/wx)^2 - (z/wz)^2];
VA[x_] := Sqrt[B0^2/\[Rho][x]]/Sqrt[B0^2/\[Rho][0]];
icX = u[0, x, z] == u0saus[x, z];
dicX = Derivative[1, 0, 0][u][0, x, z] == 0;
DX = DirichletCondition[u[t, x, z] == 0, True];
EqX = D[u[t, x, z], {t, 
      2}] - (VA[x])^2*(D[u[t, x, z], {x, 2}] + 
       D[u[t, x, z], {z, 2}]) == 0;
uwave = NDSolveValue[{EqX, icX, dicX, DX}, 
  u, {t, 0, 25}, {x, z} \[Element] Domain, Method -> {
    "PDEDiscretization" -> {"MethodOfLines",
      "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", 
        "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.3}, 
        "InterpolationOrder" -> {u -> 2}}}}]
```

Comment: Please add definitions of B0 and u0saus (and any other missing values) to your code.

Comment: I have edited the original question to include a definition of u0saus. B0 is undefined because it will cancel out, so you may define whatever you like for B0. I have only included this thing B0 for physical completeness, a term which represents the background magnetic field.

Comment: You define u0sausX but use u0saus

Comment: Further, there is something wrong with your function "centriod". The centroid should be a 3 dim point, not a scalar.

Comment: Indeed, it is a point with 3 components as you said. I used ``first`` to extract its x-component

Comment: My guess is that `DiscretizeGraphics` gives some volume to the flat bottom. And because the z dimension is much larger than the other 2, it dominates the volume.

Comment: Highly likely, we see 37.49 is just around 1/2*75. Is there a way around this so I could obtain the correct value?

Comment: ` RegionPlot3D[...] // DiscretizeGraphics // RegionDimension` evaluates to 2, so the region is actually the 2D surface embedded in 3D space.  Except for slight wrinkle (wave amplitude squared) shown at an exaggerated scale in the plot, the surface is flat.  Thus its centroid is close to, but a little off of, {0, 0, 37.5} in $(x,y,z)$ coordinates.  The extra surface area of the wrinkle pulls the centroid a little toward the wrinkle and a little "above" the $xy$-plane.    I do not know how to obtain the 3D region "under" the 2D surface.